# How to get the view count for a specific time frame in a YouTube video?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm using the YouTube v3 API to fetch the user's videos uploaded on the channel.

I need the video statistics (mainly the view count) for specific time-frames in a video. For example: from 10 second to 15 second in the video. Or maybe at the 10th second.

How can this be achieved? I have gone through the API docs but don't see any parameter or section that can provide that data.

Code snippet to fetch the data of completed livestreams / liveBroadcasts:

```
request = youtube.liveBroadcasts().list(
    part="snippet, status",
    broadcastStatus="completed",
    broadcastType="all"
)
response = request.execute()
```

Then for each video from the list data returned, I'm running the following API to fetch the video related data:

```
request = youtube.videos().list(
    part="snippet, contentDetails, statistics, liveStreamingDetails, status",
    id=videoID
)
response = request.execute()
return response
```

Sample Response

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "JI93kvK9Gsz3h2R_OvkmgPkUrqs",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "NfG5gw0fBnjykGf8db9FiaBXw3M",
      "id": "FNS_JCM-H3U",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2022-02-27T19:20:15Z",
        "channelId": "UCVxNxW5_GhdS_o8m4PyHsmg",
        "title": "Time Check Test",
        "description": "",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FNS_JCM-H3U/default_live.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FNS_JCM-H3U/mqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FNS_JCM-H3U/hqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FNS_JCM-H3U/sddefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FNS_JCM-H3U/maxresdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Streampala",
        "categoryId": "20",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "localized": {
          "title": "Time Check Test",
          "description": ""
        },
        "defaultAudioLanguage": "en-US"
      },
      "contentDetails": {
        "duration": "PT1M20S",
        "dimension": "2d",
        "definition": "sd",
        "caption": "false",
        "licensedContent": False,
        "contentRating": {},
        "projection": "rectangular",
        "hasCustomThumbnail": False
      },
      "status": {
        "uploadStatus": "uploaded",
        "privacyStatus": "public",
        "license": "youtube",
        "embeddable": False,
        "publicStatsViewable": True,
        "madeForKids": False,
        "selfDeclaredMadeForKids": False
      },
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "4",
        "likeCount": "0",
        "dislikeCount": "0",
        "favoriteCount": "0",
        "commentCount": "0"
      },
      "liveStreamingDetails": {
        "actualStartTime": "2022-02-27T19:20:33Z",
        "actualEndTime": "2022-02-27T19:21:53Z",
        "scheduledStartTime": "2022-02-27T19:20:12Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: "don't see any parameter or section that can provide that data". Have you considered the case that the API doesn't have/provide that data?

Comment: Why would you assume such data to exist? Have you seen any place where such data is displayed?

Comment: I assumed this data exists because an application apparently shows the view count of a timeframe in a youtube video. 
Perhaps they're averaging the total views or using some custom logic. 
OR there exists a way to get that value, maybe via view graph or analytics API or something.

Comment: I don't know analytics API but your problem sounds like analytics API not Data API